# How to use and save Emoji's on Laravel using Mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, emoji

I have a web app I built using Laravel 5.2 , my question is how do I store then show emoji's. At the moment when I use an emoji from my iPhone , fire for instance, after saving the database returns ???? . Ive set the 
'charset' = 'utf8mb4';
'collation' = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'

but still get the same result. Do i need to install a package or something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure you have the charset and collation correctly setup in the database config file as well, to ensure Laravel actually knows what charset to use when saving:

```
// config/database.php

'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

Comment: Tomas Buteler works like a charm, do I need to set all my text fields to  'charset' = 'utf8mb4'; 'collation' = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' or just the ones I want to use emojis on. For example to I use that setting for saving urls or anything else that required me saving text, but doesn't need emojis

Comment: I like to keep things simple: serve pages in UTF-8, save files in UTF-8 and let Laravel do the rest (with the db configuration above). As for some fields needing it and others not, I'd suggest choosing one thing and being consistent. Don't cherry-pick encoding.

Comment: Tomas Buteler Thanks, will do

Comment: It doesn't work... I have this setting and database and it still puts questionmarks

Comment: still cannot show emoji

Comment: thanks for your answer.. my problem is solved.